# Pocket IE onmousedown onmousemove onmouseup?

Tags: javascript, windows-mobile, mouseevent, pocket-ie

I have a control which I wrote for capturing signatures on a web page, by using onmousedown, onmousemove and onmouseup on a div to track the mouse, and capture points comprising a signature.

Now we need this to work on Windows Mobile 6.5 powered devices... but it seems that the div element does not support the mouse events in Pocket IE, which would seem to be supported by [this blog](http://inexorabletash.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!3FC59671BAEE20E9!1000.entry).

But [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834402.aspx#iece30_tech), the WinCE (which WinMo/PPC is based off of) version of IE does support these mouse events for some unknown list of elements.

So can anyone tell me, are there any elements: img, a, span or whatever that support onmouse[down|move|up] in WinMo 6.5 Pocket IE?

Thanks!

If not, anyone have any other ideas for capturing a signature on a web page in Pocket IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently not possible; and likely never will be now that MS has essentially EOLd WinMo in favor of the WinPhone OS.

Comment: Windows Mobile is not EOL.  Microsoft still supports it and vendors can still get it for developing WinMo 6.5 devices.  Essentially they've forked and you can get either WinPhone (for consumer devices) or WinMo 6.5 (for more business or industry targeted devices).

Comment: It hasn't *officially* been EOLd yet, no. But they've basically told developers that there will be no further support to be expected for WinMo development. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx . I have also corresponded with Microsoft hoping to get a WinMo SDK for VS 2010. They informed me there are no plans for any VS 2010 tools for WinMo, meaning that you need to use 2008 or earlier which means the development tools for it are on their way out. Phasing out the dev tools is as good as EOLing the product. Below see the text of the correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

Correspondence with Microsoft via the phasing out of WinMo...

**My Email to Microsoft**

Hello Soma,

I have 2 questions for your expertise, regarding Windows Mobile's future in development.

First, is there any idea when an SDK for WinMo 6.x will come out for VS2010? We do a lot of development for handheld barcode scanners from Honeywell/Handheld and Motorola/Symbol, which will likely be staying with 6.x for a while, and I really would like to be able to get rid of VS2008 on my machine.

And second, what does WinMo 7, and the whole app-marketplace-model of development mean for these kinds of developments? If we are writing an app for a single client, that goes on industrial-type hardware, like these barcode scanners, we would not want to put these on the marketplace, so how would we develop for WinMo7 for ISV work for industrial clients?

Thanks, and have a good day!

**Microsoft's Email to Me**

Hi,

Unfortunately there are no current plans for VS2010 to support WinMo 6.x. Vs2010 is exclusively targeting Windows Phone 7 as was announced recently at MIX conference and other related communications. We are recommending developers to continue using VS2008 for WinMo 6.x and Vs2008 does work side by side with VS2010.

I have copied Charlie from our Windows Phone 7 team and he can further elaborate on this and your second question related to the marketplace.

Thanks,
Sudeep Bharati
sudeepb@microsoft.com